# C++ Any advice on tracking down Access Violations?

Tags: c++, class, instance, destructor, access-violation

I've been having issues trying to track down an Access Violation in my program.  It occurs when the destructor is called for the third time, exactly when the destructor appears to finish.

I've spent hours trying to track this down so I'm looking for further advice on things I can do.  I'm creating the class instance with `new` and `delete` operators.  The Visual Studio output window shows:

`First-chance exception at 0x60e3ad84 (msvcp100d.dll) in WebCollationAgent.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xabababab.
Unhandled exception at 0x60e3ad84 (msvcp100d.dll) in WebCollationAgent.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xabababab.`

Is there anything I can do to try and find out what was in those memory locations?

The call stack window shows the following (in reverse order as I've pasted it in to chronological order, earliest to latest):

```
Program.exe!Network::`scalar deleting destructor'()  + 0x2b bytes   C++

Program.exe!std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >::~basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >()  Line 754 + 0xf bytes    C++

Program.exe!std::_String_val<wchar_t,std::allocator<wchar_t> >::~_String_val<wchar_t,std::allocator<wchar_t> >()  Line 478 + 0xb bytes  C++
```

> msvcp100d.dll!std::_Container_base12::_Orphan_all()  Line 214 + 0x5 bytes   C++

My best guess at this information is that there's some sort of string variable causing the issue?  Does anyone have any advice on interpreting this information?

Any other pieces of advice would also be useful, thanks in advance.

I'm coding under Windows 7 and using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Comment: [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Comment: 0xABABABAB is used by HeapAlloc as guard bytes.  You may be corrupting memory somewhere.  http://asawicki.info/news_1292_magic_numbers_in_visual_c.html

Comment: @dasblinkenlight As cool as Valgrind is, it doesn't support Windows.

Comment: I'm coding on Windows.  @RetiredNinja, is there any way I can find out what values/variables were in that section of memory in VS2010?  It might help me track down the issue as believe me I've spent hours going through my code to try and find any mistakes I may have made that could cause this.  It's happening in the destructor, and not on the first time the destructor is called for an instance of the class.

Comment: Is your class a derived class? If it is, and you're using the class in containers (like `vector`), it's important that the destructor is virtual. Otherwise, the container, when emptying, can call the wrong destructor.

Comment: @craigmj, By 'derived' do you mean is it a sub-class?  If so, then no.  If that's not what you mean, can you clarify?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. The virtual destructors are only required if it is a sub-class. Sorry, that won't help then.

Comment: @craigmj: `vector` doesn't delete its content polymorphically, even if you did have a virtual destructor.

Comment: I've had an instance (sorry!) where I was storing pointers to a derived class in a vector, then in the `delete` of my container class, running through the pointers deleting them... and of course without virtual destructors...

Comment: There are no vectors in the class, nor are instances of the class stored in a vector.

Comment: "It occurs when the destructor is called for the third time"? Why is the destructor being called more than once?

Comment: Basically, I have an instance of this class that is assigned via the 'new' operator and destroyed via the 'delete' operator.  It is the third time 'delete' comes around that it dies.  The class instance does appear to still be in existence when delete is called so I do not believe it is a case of it trying to delete it twice.

Comment: Do you delete the same pointer value more than once? Anyhow, this looks like a memory corruption, not necessarily related to a string. I recommend installing and configuring AppVerifier for your app with full page heap enabled (use both options: align allocated buffers at page beginning and at page end to see buffer overruns and underruns) and running your app under WinDbg (also needs to be installed). For some hints look at [this page](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/whatforum/thread/3aa1a3b2-9a45-49ef-9b89-2509bb3f1ba3).

Answer (score 4):

I've had success tracking memory bugs before using [BoundsChecker (now part of Borland DevPartner)](http://www.borland.com/products/devpartner/read/). There are a number of similar products that might also help: [HeapAgent](http://www.microquill.com/heapagent/index.html), and [Rational Purify](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/rational/). These seem to be much like ValGrind, but work on Windows.

Here are 3 open source alternatives that might assist:

1. [DUMA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/duma/) (by the looks of it, you'll have to build it for Windows yourself, but the README contains some notes on doing that)
2. [XMEM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmem/)
3. [elephant](http://elephant.tigris.org/)

I have no idea how these perform, but they sound very promising, and look like they all work on Windows in one way or another.

This [Microsoft page on managing memory errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/w500y392%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) might also help, and also has links to setting Memory breakpoints, which might help you find out when your data is first being deleted or altered. Good luck!

Comment: Whilst those links seem interesting, I'd prefer not to have to buy new software to resolve this.

Comment: My project is due in in less than a week, I want to have this code wrapped up in a couple of days, I cannot afford to install an operating system I am unfamiliar with and trying to code under that in an IDE I am unfamiliar with in order to use debugging software that is not guaranteed to solve the issue I am experiencing, sorry. EDIT:  The comment this comment was replying to seems to have vanished.

Comment: The BoundsChecker link is dead

Answer (score 2):

Use the Microsoft Heap Debugging stuff and hope yours is one of the cases for which it was designed.  Purify would be the next step after that.

It's built into Visual Studio and is helpful in some cases.  If it works it sure beats giving IBM two or three pockets full of cash for Purify.

You can find the info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5at7yxcs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

TL;DR
In main, do this

```
int tmpFlag = _CrtSetDbgFlag( _CRTDBG_REPORT_FLAG );
// Turn On (OR) - Keep freed memory blocks in the
// heap's linked list and mark them as freed
tmpFlag |= _CRTDBG_DELAY_FREE_MEM_DF;

// Turn on memory checking at each heap operation
tmpFlag |= _CRTDBG_CHECK_ALWAYS_DF;

// Set the new state for the flag
_CrtSetDbgFlag( tmpFlag );
```

You can toggle the `_CRTDBG_CHECK_ALWAYS_DF` flag at different places if it runs too slow.  However, I'd run it a few times with each heap op checked in order to get a feel for where the problem occurs.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this blog with some tips

http://www.atalasoft.com/cs/blogs/loufranco/archive/2007/02/06/6-_2200_Pointers_2200_-on-Debugging-Unmanaged-Code.aspx

The main thing you need to do is to get the crash or exception to happen while the code with the bug is still on the stack.  A lot of times you get Access Violation some time after the code with the bug has executed and returned and it may actually be a long time later (in computer time).  In that case, it's almost impossible to figure it out.

In your case, with the problem flagged in delete, it's a strong indicator that the heap is corrupt, and two common reasons in C++ are double-delete and mixing up array deletion (using delete when you should use delete[] or the other way around).

If you can reproduce it with simple code, I would look for the two problems above.  Otherwise, download the Microsoft Debugging Tools and use `gflags +hpa -i program.exe` to make the heap much more sensitive to corruption (it will report the error much more quickly).